# IE8 is causing many issues regarding CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

Having a few issues with Internet Explorer 8 (AGAIN).

**Problem 1:**

When trying to shrink the browser the menu is out of place and hovers over specific elements (I.E the search bar).

[image]

**Problem 2:**

When trying to shrink the browser the menu is out of place and hovers over specific elements (I.E the search bar).

[image]
I've added the Doctype, And I've tried picking apart the elements, but I can't quite see where it's going wrong?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html lang="en-US">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baumans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Set Training | Just another WordPress site</title>
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you are using fixed widths allover the place for example this id #right_header_container has 550px width added ...try using % ...
have you ever tried to use unsemantic, or any other grid system to handle smaller screen/devices I would recommend to have a look at http://unsemantic.com/

Comment: Hi, Didn't really help as using a % causes the slider to have issues. I'm also using Wordpress so using unsemantic doesn't work. Thanks